# How to fix "Can't resolve '@babel/runtime/regenerator' in npm linked module"?

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, babeljs

I'm getting that error when transpiling some of my linked (as in npm link) dependecies using webpack+babel.

I'm using latest version npm/webpack/babel. I'm having my core dependencies written in JS6 & published as NPM packages. I only bundle my webapps & higher level packages, and I configure webpack to transpile the core deps when doing so.

In other words, some of my dependencies in `node_modules` need to be transpiled. When I use the published packages (npm install) it works fine, but when I use development repositories (npm link) it's failing with that error:

> Error: Can't resolve '@babel/runtime/regenerator' in {module repository path, not under project tree}

The temporary fix I found is to `npm install --no-save @babel/runtime` in the core dependencies repositories, but this get removed each time I `npm update`, so it's quite annoying.

webpack.config.js:

```
const webpack = require('webpack')

const config = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
     {
        test: /\.(js)$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
     }
    ]
  }
}

const library = Object.assign({}, config, {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/web',
    filename: 'cosmic-lib.js',
    library: 'cosmicLib',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    globalObject: 'typeof self !== \'undefined\' ? self : this'
  },
  externals: { 'stellar-sdk': 'stellar-sdk' }
})

module.exports = [ library ]
```

I'd like to find a way to have those core dependencies transpiled in development environment without having to alter their original repository.

Comment: I think this other conversation can help you [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57690008/vuejs-module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-babel-runtime-regenerator)