# VueJS - Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@babel/runtime/regenerator'

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm, module, node-modules

I have this error

> `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@babel/runtime/regenerator' in 'C:\wamp64\www\project-dev\modules\Gallery\Resources\Assets\Backend\Views\Album'` 
>   when I execute this command `npm run dev`.

So to explain my laravel project directory:

```
app
modules
 auth
 backend
 gallery
themes
 admin
  node_modules
  resources
   js
    components
    router
     index.js
    store
    app.js
   sass
   views
  package.json
  webpack.mix.js
```

So in my `router/index.js` of vuejs app, I will includes routes from a module.

I make this:

```
import GalleryRoutes from "../../../../../modules/Gallery/Resources/Assets/Backend/routes";

// Vue Router
const router = new VueRouter({
    base: '/admin',
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        ...constantRoutes,
        ...GalleryRoutes,
    ],
    linkActiveClass: "active",
    linkExactActiveClass: "active",
});
```

`routes.js` file from Gallery module:

```
// Views
import AlbumIndex from './Views/Album/Index.vue'

// Routes
export default [
    // AlbumIndex
    {

        path: 'gallery/albums',
        component: AlbumIndex,
        name: 'backend.gallery.album.index',
        meta: {
            heading: 'Gallery',
            title: 'Albums',
            icon: 'fas fa-images',
            showed: true
        }
    }
];
```

But I get the error above.

I think this is a bug related to the `node_modules` folder, I'm not sure.
It's possible to achieve what I want to do? (include .Vue or .js files from outside my root app directory).

PS: I try to make this to try to answer this question: [Backend (VueJS) of laravel application with modules approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57673764/backend-vuejs-of-laravel-application-with-modules-approach)

Thank you to helping me :)

Answer (score 4):

It's looking for a dependency that is not installed. In your case you can do `npm i babel-runtime --save` to install that dependency you're missing.

Comment: That's what's weird, I have this dependency installed :/
This is not related to the directory path node_modules?

Comment: May I see your node_modules folder list? @Nunu

Comment: I am having the same issue I have tried what you have suggested but having the same error

Comment: Use `npm install --save @babel/runtime` instead

Answer (score 0):

Installing [whatwg-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/whatwg-fetch) fixed the issue for me